# How to run a Task N times until it succeeds?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task

Am working with C#'s TaskFactory using ContinueWith function. The issue am trying to solve it this

- Execute Foo().
- If result succeeded, exit
- If Foo() did not result in success, then iterate and execute Foo() until it results in success (max iterations 3)
- If it doesn't succeed in 3 iterations, give up

The code I started with looks like this

```
var executeTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<ExecutionStatus>(() =>
        {
            return Foo();
        });
        executeTask.ContinueWith(task => CheckIfExecutionWasSuccessful(task)).
                        ContinueWith(task => CheckIfExecutionWasSuccessful(task)).
                        ContinueWith(task => CheckIfExecutionWasSuccessful(task)).
                        ContinueWith(task => CheckLastTimeBeforeGivingUp(task));
```

Foo() and CheckIfExecutionWasSuccessful() looks like this

```
ExecutionStatus Foo(){
      //Do my work
      return new ExecutionStatus(){Succeded = true}
     }

ExecutionStatus CheckIfExecutionWasSuccessful(Task<ExecutionStatus> task){
            if(task.Result.Succeeded) return task.Result;
            else return Foo()
```

Something tells me that this is not the best way to go about this problem. Any suggestions, ideas?

Comment: Are you using >=.net45? If so, you really should go `async/await` instead of using `.ContinueWith`.

Comment: We are on .NET 4.0, I dont have the luxury to change it to 4.5. Am curious though, how would I go about this if am using async/await

Comment: You could just use a simple loop with async/await

Comment: I could, but isn't this exactly the reason why we have Task.ContinueWith() ? I just need to figure out how I can conditionally invoke ContinueWith() without having to have a predicate inside CheckIfExecutionWasSuccessful()

Comment: Also it would be awesome if I can specify the number of iterations, instead of having to call ContinueWith() three times

Comment: Basically your issue is a solved problem using a two-year-old technology.  Your code would be drastically simpler.

Comment: `Observable.Retry(Foo, 15).ToTask()` although `TaskFactory` in .net 4 is actually broken, (see `SynchronizationContext`). You could also think about using the async targeting pack.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21346870/1768303) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21324583/1768303).

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why are you making this more complicated by using multiple `Task`s and `ContinueWith()`. Instead, write the code just like you would without `Task`s and *then* run it in a `Task`:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < maxTries - 1; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            return Foo();
        }
        catch
        { }
    }

    return Foo();
});
```

This makes the code clearer, more obviously correct and easier to modify.

Comment: This should propagate the exception if all attempts fail, rather than indicating success.

Comment: @Servy It will, that's why the last call to Foo() is outside of the try.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
var MaxTries = 3;
var executeTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<ExecutionStatus>(() => Foo());

for(var i = 0; i < MaxTries; i++)
{
    executeTask = executeTask.ContinueWith(task => CheckIfExecutionWasSuccessful(task));
}

executeTask = executeTask.ContinueWith(task => CheckLastTimeBeforeGivingUp(task));
```

Comment: But this is going to execute CheckIfExecutionWasSuccesful() three times regardless of whether the task was successful or not, isnt it?

Comment: absolutely it does, what if CheckIfExecutionWasSuccessful is an expensive call. Am not saying in my case it is, am just curious to find out the best way possible